# update the last row with search criteria in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

below is my collection :

```
db.himtest.find({name:"himanshu"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f1667611c54cf649076577"), "name" : "himanshu", "age" : 45,
 "points" : 10 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("56f1667c11c54cf649076578"), "name" : "himanshu", "age"   : 35,
"points" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f1669511c54cf64907657b"), "name" : "himanshu", "age" : 35,
 "points" : 1100 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("56f1669a11c54cf64907657c"), "name" : "himanshu", "age" : 35,
 "points" : 11000 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("56f1669d11c54cf64907657d"), "name" : "himanshu", "age" : 45,
  "points" : 11000 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("56f166a311c54cf64907657e"), "name" : "himanshu", "age" : 45,
     "points" : 1200 }
```

Now i want to update the last row on the basis of any selection criteria something like :

```
    db.himtest.find({name:"himanshu",age:45}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).update({points:100});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db-collection-findandmodify) which lets you include a sort specification to identify which of the matched documents to update:

```js
db.himtest.findAndModify({
  query: {name: "himanshu", age: 45},
  sort: {_id: -1},
  update: {$set: {points: 100}},
  new: true
})
```

If you're using v3.2 or above, you can also use [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/):

```js
db.himtest.findOneAndUpdate(
    {name: "himanshu", age: 45},
    {$set: {points: 100}},
    {
        sort: {_id: -1},
        returnNewDocument: true
    })
```

Comment: Should probably use [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) considering that even though the "shell" documentation doesn't yet mark as deprecated, all other API documentation does. It's also consistent between language API's. Surprised this question was not asked before.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yeah, but it wasn't clear if the OP was at 3.2 so I went with the least-common-denominator option. Anyway, good idea -- added.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this.

```
db.himtest.find({name:"himanshu",age:45}).
  sort({id:-1}).
  limit(1).
  forEach(function(e){
  e.points = 100
  db.himtest.save(e)
})
```

Not sure if you are using something like mongoose, or the mongodb shell.  If you specify I can test to make sure the answer will work.

Comment: i am using the mongodb shell

Comment: See updated answer.  Let me know how that works for you.